# Day and night effects on Natural Enviroment

Tags: human-influence

What are the effects of "day" and "night" on natural environment,including life of humans,animals,plants and other creatures (as well as effects on biochemical reactions in the nature)?
Can anyone introduce a good source or explain me about that?

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science stack exchange!  Your question has been closed by the community because it is too broad.  Any question that would require something on  the order of a wikipedia article to answer is too broad.  If you narrowed your question down to a specific effect of the diurnal cycle you could avoid being too broad.  Also note that biological processes questions are better asked on the Biology stack exchange site.